# What is the best practise of managing database in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

Could any one let me know how do we manage (merge) local database changes between different branches that need to be replicated to all developers?

For example, two developers have finished something in code and database in their own branches. I can merge the code with git but how do I deal with the database?

Is the module Configuration Manager helpful enough?

We are using git, Acquia Dev Desktop and Acquia Cloud.

Thanks for any input!

Comment: This is exactly the reason configuration management was introduced into Drupal 8. There are plenty of examples, demos and tutorials on the interwebs about it. "Is it helpful enough?" is a question only someone who knows your project can answer.

Comment: Thanks I will check them out.